# Weird bug with PHP / Mysql mysql_query and mysql_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue and I don't understand what's happening.
I have a mysql query that works perfectly. It's supposed to return a row in a table.

```
$res = mysql_query($query);     
$myobj = mysql_fetch_object($res);
```

When I do :

```
var_dump($myobj);
```

It returns:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (25) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["cookie"]=> string(3) "yes" ["nb_pts_per_question"]=> string(2) "50" ["product"]=> string(10) "MyProduct" } bool(false)
```

The object sounds complete but at the end of the var_dump you can see a bool(false)

Again, the query works fine when I run it into mysql.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give the full code on where you put your `var_dump`

Comment: Here's the full code: function _construct () { $query = "..."; $res = mysql_query($query);     
$myobj = mysql_fetch_object($res); var_dump($myobj); } no loop, nothing special :(

Comment: Does this still happen if you put a `die();` immediately after ` var_dump($myobj);`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a stray `var_dump`. Don't you put your `var_dump`in a while loop ? That would explain the `bool (false)`

Comment: Nope, it's not in a loop there's nothing special around the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a little strange...

Just by curiosity, what output is giving print_r($myobj) ?

In the end, does using your object work?

Comment: The print_r gives stdClass Object ( [id] => 10 [cookie] => yes [nb_pts_per_question] => 50 [product] => Product ) and in the end, the object doesn't work :(

Comment: Maybe the fact that it returns (bool)false is a reason for the Object not to work. Did you try to use fetch_row instead?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `mysql_fetch_object()` thats why u are getiing this result, please see this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php. You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: The problem isn't that it's an stdClass object, it's the `bool (false)` at the end of the object dump.

Comment: Err...are you trying to say this boolean value indicates this is the last row in the result set? Why else are you linking to this? :)

Answer (score -1):

The `bool(false)` value is there are no more data indicator
See in [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)
it says that

```
Return Values

Returns an object with string properties that correspond to the fetched row,  
or FALSE if there are no more rows.
```